# Boost "undefined reference" errors even with -lboost_thread

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm getting some strange compiler/linker errors when trying to use boost::shared_mutex. I'm using boost v1.61 on a VM running 32-bit rhel 6.2.

Code that causes error:

hpp file:

```
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>

class SharedData
{
public:
  SharedData();
  ~SharedData();

  void packMessage(std::shared_ptr<Message> s);

private:
  // mutex that allows multiple read, single write protection
  boost::shared_mutex m_sharedMutex;
};
```

cpp file:

```
void SharedData::packMessage(std::shared_ptr<Message> s)
{
  // get shared read access
  boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(m_sharedMutex); // <- this line causes the errors

  // read stuff here
}
```

`make` output:

```
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(pthread_mutex_t*, pthread_cond_t*)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:195: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o: In function `boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:81: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o: In function `boost::shared_mutex::lock_shared()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:186: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:193: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:193: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/tester] Error 1
```

Everywhere I've searched has said that these errors mean I need to link the boost_thread library, which I've done in my cmake file (`boost_system` is included for other code in this same project):

```
target_link_libraries(${BINARY_NAME} boost_thread boost_system)
```

But the errors persist.

Originally I was using the boost 1.41 libraries that were already installed on my machine. When I hit these errors I ran `yum remove boost-devel` and then manually installed boost 1.61 to see if that would correct the errors. Is there something extra I needed to add to the `./bootstrap.sh` or `./b2 install` commands? I can see `libboost_thread.a` in `/usr/local/lib`, so I assumed that meant the thread library was built correctly.

Any thoughts on what is causing these errors? Thanks!

Edit:
Cmake's log didn't have anything useful I could see, but `make VERBOSE=1` gives the following output:

```
cd /home/craig/dev/myProject/build/test && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/tester.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11 -ggdb -Wall -Werror -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -O0 -pedantic    -Wl,--export-dynamic CMakeFiles/tester.dir/utilities/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/tester.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/SharedData/testSharedData.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/Common/testFifo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/Common/testCsu.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/Messages/testMessage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/Common/Fifo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/Common/Csu.cpp.o  -o ../bin/tester -rdynamic -lboost_system -lpthread 
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(pthread_mutex_t*, pthread_cond_t*)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:195: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o: In function `boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:81: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/__/src/SharedData/SharedData.cpp.o: In function `boost::shared_mutex::lock_shared()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:186: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:193: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:193: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
```

Comment: Please show a compile and link command invocation, and not just what Cmake chooses to show. I think you can find it in the cmake log file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my question is just like everyone else's.

@jww suggested I show the actual compile and link command invocation, not CMake's output, which I've added to my question. As you can see, the command is linking `boost_system` and `pthread`, but not `boost_thread`.

Digging into my project I realized that I had added `boost_thread` to my release build, but not into my unit test build, which is what I was trying to compile. Adding `boost_thread` to the unit test's CMakeLists.txt removed the error immediately.